# iPhone Facebook login screen issues

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

In my app I have a button that allows you to post to Facebook. If you have not yet allowed the app access to your Facebook, you must login.

```
        [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(doThePost) andExtendedPermissions:@"publish_stream"];
```

This line above is what brings up the web view with the Facebook login. My app is landscape only though, and the login page loads in portrait. When the text is tapped, the keyboard loads in landscape and covers the page. Also, if you hit "Done" on the keyboard you are stuck in the web view (I can't get a back button on it).

I haven't done much with Facebook in apps, does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Here is an image
http://cl.ly/1X413w2G1S3t102T1R0o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this link](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=37780) might hopefully help you get started on a fix for the orientation problem.

In regards to adding a back/dismiss button the following might be of some use:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {


if (hasHitFinishCallback == NO)
{
    //add our own cancel button
    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cancelButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 7, 57, 31)];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissAuthenticationView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [webView addSubview:cancelButton];
    [webView bringSubviewToFront:cancelButton];

    hasHitFinishCallback = YES;
}

}

- (void)dismissAuthenticationView:(id)sender
{
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I was able to get a close button added; thanks! But I followed the instructions on the link you supplied about the whole portrait issue, and that did not resolve it; Ill have to dig around some more .

Comment: just FYI if you are having login issues with facebook graph API at the moment, facebook have made a slight change to the URL they return when you make a request. It used to have "method=permissions.request" in it  but now it leaves out the "method=" part.